# Issue with Django Serializers when fields are from many tables FK

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i a newi'm trying to understand how serializers from django works when we have multiple fields from multiple tables, and this fields are related with FK.

My Goal is retrieve all informations in one Json.

I create a scenario ti post here,

My Models:

```
class operacoes(models.Model):

# Fields
date = models.DateTimeField()


class Meta:
    ordering = ('-pk',)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.pk

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('sales_operacoes_detail', args=(self.pk,))


def get_update_url(self):
    return reverse('sales_operacoes_update', args=(self.pk,))


class type(models.Model):

# Fields
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
description = models.TextField(max_length=100)

# Relationship Fields
venda_operacoes = models.ForeignKey(
    'sales.operacoes',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="types", 
)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-pk',)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.pk

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('sales_type_detail', args=(self.pk,))


def get_update_url(self):
    return reverse('sales_type_update', args=(self.pk,))


class car(models.Model):

# Fields
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

# Relationship Fields
car_type_relate = models.OneToOneField(
    'sales.type',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="cars", 
)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-pk',)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.pk

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('sales_car_detail', args=(self.pk,))


def get_update_url(self):
    return reverse('sales_car_update', args=(self.pk,))


class source_car(models.Model):

# Fields
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
brand = models.TextField(max_length=100)
price = models.TextField(max_length=100)

# Relationship Fields
source_car_car = models.OneToOneField(
    'sales.car',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="source_cars", 
)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-pk',)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.pk

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('sales_source_car_detail', args=(self.pk,))


def get_update_url(self):
    return reverse('sales_source_car_update', args=(self.pk,))


class bike(models.Model):

# Fields
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

# Relationship Fields
bike_sales_related = models.OneToOneField(
    'sales.type',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="bikes", 
)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-pk',)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.pk

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('sales_bike_detail', args=(self.pk,))


def get_update_url(self):
    return reverse('sales_bike_update', args=(self.pk,))


class source_bike(models.Model):

# Fields
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
brand = models.TextField(max_length=100)
price = models.TextField(max_length=100)


class Meta:
    ordering = ('-pk',)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.pk

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('sales_source_bike_detail', args=(self.pk,))


def get_update_url(self):
    return reverse('sales_source_bike_update', args=(self.pk,))
```

I Created a endpoint for the models: 
Thats retrieve one for one:

```
from . import models
```

from rest_framework import serializers

```
class operacoesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = models.operacoes
    fields = (
        'pk', 
        'date', 
    )


class typeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = models.type
    fields = (
        'pk', 
        'name', 
        'description', 
    )


class carSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = models.car
    fields = (
        'pk', 
        'name', 
    )


class source_carSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = models.source_car
    fields = (
        'pk', 
        'name', 
        'brand', 
        'price', 
    )


class bikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = models.bike
    fields = (
        'pk', 
        'name', 
    )


class source_bikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = models.source_bike
    fields = (
        'pk', 
        'name', 
        'brand', 
        'price', 
    )
```

Now i need to create a endpoint able to do like a join in all tables and retrieves data, i tryed a lot of thinks, but no sucess.

My Expected Json for example is something like this:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "date": "2020-01-10",
    "type": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "operacao_id": 1
            "car": [
                {
                    "id": 2
                    "type_id": 1
                    "name": "Ferrari"
                    "Source_car_id": [
                        {
                            name: "Ferrari LXT 678"
                            price: "U$ 80000000,00"
                        }
                    ]

                }


            ]
        }
    ]
},
    {
    "id": 2,
    "date": "2020-01-11",
    "type": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "operacao_id": 2
            "car": [
                {
                    "id": 12
                    "type_id": 1
                    "name": "Fusca"
                    "Source_car_id": [
                        {
                            name: "Fusca 1600"
                            price: "U$ 4000,00"
                        }
                    ]

                }


            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "operacao_id": 2
            "bike": [
                {
                    "id": 12
                    "type_id": 3
                    "name": "Bike Harley"
                    "Source_bike_id": [
                        {
                            name: "Bike Harley lc409"
                            price: "U$ 44000,00"
                        }
                    ]

                }


            ]
        }
    ]
},
    {
    "id": 3,
    "date": "2020-01-10",
    "type": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "operacao_id": 3
            "car": [
                {
                    "id": 2
                    "type_id": 1
                    "name": "Ferrari"
                    "Source_car_id": [
                        {
                            name: "Kombi Volks 1234"
                            price: "U$ 85000000,00"
                        }
                    ]

                }


            ]
        }
    ]
},
```

Like a Join relating all tables.

What is the best way to do a endpoint retrieving this datas?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to define serializers for each model, instead you can use [`depth`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) property to serialize nested objects with django rest framework like this:

```
class operacoesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.operacoes
        fields = (
            'pk', 
            'date', 
            'types',
        )
        depth = 3
```

This will generate nested objects with 3 level of nesting.

Comment: 3 is the level of deep?

Comment: if my FK weren't in table operacoes but in table type? Type related a operacoes?

Comment: @ThiagoBueno yes, but you need to add related_name `'types'` to serializer fields explicitly.